# Converting XAML to XHTML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I need to convert X(A)ML to XHTML using XSLT.

Following is the XAML input data :

```
<Section>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="plain 1 " />
    <Span Text="bold" FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text=" plain 2 " />
    <Span Text="italic" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" plain3 " />
    <Span Text="underline" UnderlineDecoration="line" />
    <Span Text="Bold" FontWeight="bold" />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="plain " />
    <Span Text="Italic" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" plain " />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="BoldItalic" FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="plain " />
    <Span Text=" Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text=" BoldItalic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" BoldItalicUnderline " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" UnderlineDecoration="line" />
    <Span Text=" BoldItalic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text=" plain " />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="plain " />
    <Span Text="BoldItalicUnderline " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" UnderlineDecoration="line" />
    <Span Text=" plain " />
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>
    <Span Text="plain " />
    <Span Text="Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text=" Bold and Italic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" Bold and Italic and Underline " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" UnderlineDecoration="line" />
    <Span Text=" Bold and Italic " FontWeight="bold" FontStyle="italic" />
    <Span Text=" Bold " FontWeight="bold" />
    <Span Text=" plain " />
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

Expected XHTML data as output using XSLT:

```
<QuestionText xml:space="preserve">
  <p>plain 1 <b>bold</b> plain 2 <i>italic</i> plain3 <u>underline</u><b>Bold</b></p>
  <p>plain <i>Italic</i> plain </p>
  <p><b><i>BoldItalic</i></b></p>
  <p>plain <b> Bold <i> BoldItalic <u> BoldItalicUnderline </u> BoldItalic </i> Bold </b> plain </p>
  <p>plain <b><i><u>BoldItalicUnderline </u></i></b> plain </p>
  <p>plain <b>Bold <i> Bold and Italic <u> Bold and Italic and Underline </u> Bold and Italic </i> Bold </b> plain </p>
</QuestionText>
```

I don't know how to convert all the Span(sibling) nodes into one parent node.

Any help on XSLT to transform the above XAML to XHTML is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a template for each non-plain `<Span>`, with elevated priority:

```
 match="Span[@FontWeight = 'bold']" priority="2"
```

etc. The content would be something like

```
 <b><xsl:value-of select="@Text" /></b>
```

Then have a template that matches the remaining `<Span>` elements, with lower priority:

```
match="Span" priority="1"
```

The content of the latter can be

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Text" />
```

Actually the default priorities of these templates will be such that the "Span" template will have lower priority than the others, roughly because it's less specific. So you don't *have* to add the `priority` attribute. But your code will be more readable, predictable and maintainable if you make the priorities explicit.

Note that for XHTML output, you have to have the XHTML namespace declared as the default output namespace in order for the above `<b>` to be correct. But I'll assume you have that covered.

If you want help with the style combination aspect of the problem (simultaneous italic, bold, underline), let me know.

## Update

In response to the comment about combination of styles, here is a stylesheet that does it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="Section">
    <QuestionText xml:space="preserve">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </QuestionText>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Paragraph">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates select="*" /></p>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Span">
    <xsl:variable name="bold">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@FontWeight='bold'"><b><xsl:value-of select="@Text"/></b></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="@Text"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="italic">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@FontStyle='italic'"><i><xsl:copy-of select="$bold"/></i></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="$bold"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@UnderlineDecoration='line'"><u><xsl:copy-of select="$italic"/></u></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="$italic"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your sample input, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><QuestionText xml:space="preserve">

  <p>plain 1 <b>bold</b> plain 2 <i>italic</i> plain3 <u>underline</u><b>Bold</b></p>
  <p>plain <i>Italic</i> plain </p>
  <p><i><b>BoldItalic</b></i></p>
  <p>plain <b> Bold </b><i><b> BoldItalic </b></i><u><i><b> BoldItalicUnderline </b></i></u><i><b> BoldItalic </b></i><b> Bold </b> plain </p>
  <p>plain <u><i><b>BoldItalicUnderline </b></i></u> plain </p>
  <p>plain <b>Bold </b><i><b> Bold and Italic </b></i><u><i><b> Bold and Italic and Underline </b></i></u><i><b> Bold and Italic </b></i><b> Bold </b> plain </p>

    </QuestionText>
```

Comment: I don't have control over to set the priority.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Please ignore my previous comment. Can you please help me with the style combination aspect of the problem. I am relatively new to XSLT.

Comment: @teenboy: Can you use XSLT 2.0, or are you restricted to 1.0? Because if you can use 2.0, there are some features that make it much easier.

Comment: Thanks For that LarsH. Your help is highly appreciated. One (hopefully) final question, how can I prevent the line-break anything between <p>...<p> until explicitly specified.

Comment: @teenboy: in the `"Paragraph"` template, add `select="*"` to the apply-templates. This will prevent it from copying the (whitespace) text nodes between the `<p>` elements, which it would do otherwise by default. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30344/discussion-between-teenboy-and-larsh)